# Is there a way to be able to apply the Kineticist's Chain form infusion to the Thunderstorm composite blast?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, kineticist

I have been looking at all the Kineticist rules and archetypes, but maybe I'm just missing something. As written, the Chain infusion can only be applied to an electric (simple) blast, but I am building an all-air/electric Kineticist with the Thunderstorm composite blast (think Storm from Marvel) and applying Chain to it would be fantastic as well as thematic.

Basically I am looking for ways to maximize damage output, and most of the area of effect infusions are rather weak.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, you cannot use the Physical Composite **Thunderstorm Blast** with the Energy Form Infusion **Chain**.

You could definitely petition your GM to bypass RAW for your purpose, though, especially if you use the Elemental Purist archetype and limit it to the one exception.